# Counting in the Subsummary AND over the Found Set, same value different fields - FileMaker 12

Tags: filemaker

Hard to think of a good title for this.

I have a table with Agents and Referrals. The data shows in subsummary parts which are sorted by Agent.

It's easy to get a count when Agent = Referral.

However, is it possible to get a count of Referrals over the whole found set when sorted by Agent?

For example, Smith was the Agent for 10 records.

Smith was also the Referral for 8 records, 3 where Smith was the Agent and 5 where Jones was the agent.

On the subsummary part, sorted by Agent, I can get the 3 for when Smith is the Agent and Referral. How can I put on that same part that Smith is the Refferal for 8 records in the found set?

I was thinking of maybe Execute SQL but I don't know enough SQL to write a meaningful statement. Or should I go with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on how you have this set up, but I'm going to assume you are only dealing with the two tables you mentioned -- Referrals, and Agents -- and that your report is based on the Referrals table, which has two relevant fields: Referrer, and Agent.

The first thing to realize is that, if you are trying to report on a found set of Referrals, subsummarized by Agent, you cannot have a Referral record show up in Smith's subsummary AND Jones' subsummary ... it is either/or.

I can think of a few ways to produce the report you are looking for:

1. Instead of reporting on the entire found set, report on smaller found sets (by person), and then assemble your report by appending each individual found set report to each other.  For example: create a script that would find all Referrals with Smith as either the agent or the referrer, and that will give you a found set (and count) of 18 (from your example); iterate through all agents, and assemble the report from the collected data.
2. Create a new child table of the Referral table, with records for each instance of a Referral's referrer, as well as each instance of a Referral's agent (**but only when different from the referrer**) ... then, report from that table instead.
3. As you suggest, this sounds like it can be done using the ExecuteSQL command.  I don't know what kind of output you are looking for, and your field names will be different (I used "AgentName", "agent", and "referrer"), but it would be something like:

   ```
   Go To Layout [ "Agents" ]
   Show All
   Go To Record/Request [ First ]
   Loop
       Set Variable [ $ThisAgent ; AgentName & " referrals: " & Evaluate ( ExecuteSQL ( "SELECT 1 FROM Referrals WHERE ( agent LIKE 'SMITH' OR referrer LIKE 'SMITH')" ; "" ; "+" ) ) ]
       Set Variable [ $ReportText ; List ( $ReportText ; $ThisAgent ) ]
       Go To Record/Request [ Exit after last, Next ]
   End Loop
   set Variable [ $$MergeVariableForReportDisplay ; $ReportText ]
   ```